# eth.pendingTransactions vs eth.getBlock('pending').transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions

What is the difference between `eth.pendingTransactions` and `eth.getBlock('pending').transactions`?

I have noticed that sometimes `eth.pendingTransactions` have some transactions that `eth.getBlock('pending').transactions` does not have.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`eth.pendingTransactions` are the transactions that your **local Geth** node has, that haven't been mined to a block.

[`eth.getBlock('pending')`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethdefaultblock) is the current block your node is mining (or would be mining on).  It is not a block that has been added to the blockchain.  `eth.getBlock('pending').transactions` are the transactions that are included in this hypothetical block.

If you are sending a transaction, you will see it first in `eth.pendingTransactions`, before a miner includes it in a block.

Comment: Does eth.pendingTransactions only contain tx created by the own node or also tx broadcasted by others? Or in other words: Is it possible to know about incoming ether payment transactions before they are confirmed in a block (like in btc)

Comment: @tobi For Geth you can take a look at [txpool](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#txpool)

Comment: cool, thanks! So probably for parity too, right? I'm just starting to look into it but my assumption is that their rpc interfaces are quite similar

Comment: @eth Hi, is this true for a node that's not mining ? I can't see what that "hypothetical block" could represent on a non-mining node when using "pending" as parameter.

Comment: @NicolasMassart If not mining, 'pending' would be the same as 'latest' block (your node has). If there's a difference, may be worth linking a new question.