# Is it normal pending transaction are removed after restart of geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, pending-transactions

I enter a transaction in the account of my main node to transfer 100 to the account of another node. As I am not mining a pending transactions is created, which I see in my overview including a transaction id/hash. When I stop the geth the process for my main node and restart the geth process the pending transactions has dissapeared and is not in my list anymore. When I start mining nothing is processed, so the 100 is never transferred. Is this correct behavior?

ps. if I do not restart my mainnode and start mining the pending transactions are correctly processed, so the processing of pending transactions itself is not the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's normal Geth behavior.

[`eth.pendingTransactions`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#ethpendingtransactions) are the transactions that your local Geth node has, that haven't been mined to a block.  Geth does not persist these anywhere, so they are gone when Geth is restarted.

You can also see that `eth.pendingTransactions` is an [addition to Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#eth) and not part of [`web3.eth`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3eth).  (There's also [eth.pendingTransactions vs eth.getBlock('pending').transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6720/eth-pendingtransactions-vs-eth-getblockpending-transactions).)