# How do I get information on pending transactions of a wallet/contract?

Tags: web3js, transactions, etherscan, web3.py, external-api

I have tried so many API such as Etherscan, Moralis, and Blockcypher but they all only display completed transactions. Is there a way to scan a wallets' pending transaction and get information out of it?

I'm currently using web3-py, but any information will be a big help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So basically your askin how to monitor the mempool. This is the place where all transactions go after submitting in waiting to be included in some block.

[Here you can find more details.](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/defi/how-to-access-ethereum-mempool)

[This also might be helpful](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26402/get-pending-transactions-to-a-given-address-contract?rq=1)