# How to find a Pending txn with a lower account nonce

Tags: pending-transactions

For example I have this transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe76ff4f05f32f077098f671c362a32b0650a9d1d12aaa8069fa39e0726c1ecf4 which is pending because there are lower nonce transactions which were stuck. Is there a way to find out such information that the transaction is gonna pending due to another transaction? Etherscan API only tells me whether transaction is confirmed or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can look at the sender's pending transactions in Etherscan `https://etherscan.io/txsPending?a=0x5ae2519422b191155e9236382cbff1e2f55a1b82&m=hf`. That particular address has 32 pending transaction, because it started sending transactions with nonce equal to 1, but nonces start from 0 for EOAs.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently we need an ethereum node to access to mempool, however we won't be able to get all pending transactions according to this link [Get pending transactions to a given address/contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26402/get-pending-transactions-to-a-given-address-contract)