# How to query for all pending txs in web3

Tags: web3js

I've been mining testnet in http://testnet.oracles.org:4000/tx/pending Proof-of-Authority network.
I'd like to know how to query for all pending txs using `web3.js`

Comment: did you see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6720/eth-pendingtransactions-vs-eth-getblockpending-transactions/6725#6725 ?